# Javascript - return(xmlhttp.responseText) not working

Tags: javascript, xml

can someone please tell me why this isn't working? 
For some reason I need more text for this amount of code... cant really see how this could benefit anybody but whatever have some more text.....

This:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

    {
        alert("rS4Xs200");
    var string33 = xmlhttp.responseText;
    //document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
            return(string33);

    }
  }
  var urlToGet = 'd2/two.php';
  alert(urlToGet);
xmlhttp.open("GET",urlToGet,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Returns:

```
undefined
```

Comment: Because xmlhttp.responseText is not defined.

Comment: Post your entire xhr code. And possibly the applicable server code

Comment: entire script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/884180/

Comment: With the code provided I cannot see a problem. However there is very limited code to work with. You can try using [this](https://github.com/rlemon/Little-XHR) which I know to work, however without more information, including what the server expected return is I don't know if I can be more help.

Comment: What is the MIME type of the data being returned by `d2/two.php`?  Is it `text/plain`?

Comment: Yea, it's simply "user|port|dir" in the php file

Comment: the xmlhttp.responseText is fine (when using document.write(xmlhttp.responseText); it works) but idk how to get it to return the data to the runajax document.write :/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/884191/ try that

Comment: That just alerts the result, I want it to the return the value so I can put it in a variable outside of the function etc.

Comment: Not an actual solution to why the return doesn't work but if you want to put the return value in a variable outside the function just declare a global variable outside the function then assign it the value inside the function.

Comment: King that is an example.  i cannot assune you do not know the basics .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's showing "undefined" is because the AJAX request is asynchronous and therefore your script calls the AJAXrequestDLC() function and eventually sends the xmlHttpp request, but it then moves on to the write command containing that function call before the onreadystatechange function is fired (because the response hasn't been returned yet).  You can verify this by changing your code to something like:

```
function runAJAX2() {
var result = AJAXrequestDLC();
alert('boom');
document.write(result);
}
```

You'll notice that the "boom" alert comes before the alerts in the onreadystatechange function in your code, indicating that the script has moved on while waiting for the response from your PHP file.

EDIT: Rewritten this answer twice and I still confuse myself a bit so here's an alternative explanation:

1. Function runAJAX() is called
2. document.write(AJAXrequestDLC()); invokes the AJAXrequestDLC() function
3. Within the AJAXrequestDLC function, the xmlHTTP request is sent
4. At this point program flow returns to the document.write command, which writes the current value of AJAXrequestDLC() (which is undefined).
5. At some time microseconds later, the response is returned from the php script and the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange event fires, calling the inline function.  However since program flow has already moved on, the return statement has no effect.

Comment: Can i not delay script execution until the xmlresponse is filled?

Comment: You can but the downside to doing so would be if for some reason your php script took a long time to respond your script (and browser) would hang waiting for the response.  However if you want to do it this is a good explanation: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX

Comment: it's not a php script it's a html page :) the ajax call is all it does so i doubt it could ever take too long to respond

Comment: Thanks though :) thats pretty much what I wanted